# Scheduling a java.util.concurrent.Callable through Spring means

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

The Spring `org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler` is different from the JDK `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService` in the way that it does not allow scheduling a `java.util.concurrent.Callable` with a fixed delay (it can just schedule `java.lang.Runnable`s).

Is there a Spring-based alternative to the `ScheduledExecutorService` available (that is automatically shut down on context destruction) that supports scheduling `Callable`s?

Comment: It does not allow returning a result.

Comment: you're right, you can submit a Callable to a [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)), but you can only schedule a Runnable. Why can't you use ScheduledExecutorService directly?

Comment: I'd like to have the thread pool shut down automatically when the Spring context is destroyed. My current workaround for this is to use a DisposableBean for this task, but it would be nice to have this as part of the framework.

Comment: went to lunch and @alf beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only thing you need is shutdown, use `destroy-method`:

```
<bean id="threadPool" class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" 
      factory-method="newFixedThreadPool"
      destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="6"/>
</bean>
```

Works just fine for us.

PS. You may need to use `factory-method="newScheduledThreadPool"` instead.