# Why ThreadPoolTaskScheduler does not support schedule for Callable

Tags: spring, spring-3

I am doing some experiments and I did realize about the Spring's [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html) API

It only has these **schedule** methods:

```
ScheduledFuture<?>  schedule(Runnable task, Date startTime)
ScheduledFuture<?>  schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger)
```

Why **ThreadPoolTaskScheduler** does not support **schedule** for **Callable**?

If I check the JDK's [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) API I can see these methods:

```
ScheduledFuture<?>  schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit)
<V> ScheduledFuture<V>  schedule(Callable<V> callable, long delay, TimeUnit unit)
```

At GitHub I can see that [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler's createExecutor method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.java#L128) creates a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html)

I don't know why Spring done this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: See related question (but not a duplicate) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049211/scheduling-a-java-util-concurrent-callable-through-spring-means

Comment: Thanks, I already have read before to create my post, but there is no a clear answer or explanation. The author of that post is more interested about the *shutdown*

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no specific reason so please create an issue.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this two years later, and this still seems to be missing. Surely this can't be such a rare use-case to schedule a callable that no-one noticed it's still missing?

Comment: @kasoban the jira issue has 2 votes. Feel free to add yours.